# Associate custom post type with post or user

Tags: wordpress, post, custom-post-type

I have posts of different users and I created a custom_post_type named "offers". When users login in wordpress only can see his own Post and Offers.

Is it possible to associate the offer with post of user (user only can create one post?

The question is: Can I show icon in post of index.php and archive.php when the user of post have "Offers"?

Comment: Actually, what you are trying to achieve is a little hackish, but I think you can if you give different capabilities to your users and associates capabilities with ability to view the menu item and to edit these items, look: http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities

Comment: thanks @LouisXIV I have thats capabilities. The user only can see his own offers and entries. The problem is, i want show the offer icon in index.php (posts) if the user have Offers. Some idea?

Comment: @LouisXIV i improved the question (i think :) )

Comment: @LouisXIV do you know someone or website where i can pay for fix this? Or you. thanks

Comment: No sorry and it's not my thing, maybe give a try on http://www.freelancer.com/ . Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want to do a loop in a loop? I don't know if it is the most efficient way to do it but I suppose it will work:

```
<?php 
// First loop
while ( have_posts() ): the_post(); 
$author_id = get_query_var('author');
    $offers = array();

    // Second Loop
    $i = 0;
    $args = array(
        'author' => $author_id,
        'post_type' => 'offers'
    );
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ($the_query->have_posts()) : 
        while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post(); // check if it has offers, if it has, loop over the offers
            $offers[$i]['title'] = get_the_title(); // or anything you need
            $i++;
        endwhile; // close the loop
    else: // if it has no post
        continue; // we don't display the post
    endif;

    wp_reset_postdata(); 
    ?>
<div class="post">
<?php
the_title(); // or anything you need

foreach ($offers as $offer):
    echo $offer['title']; // we display the title of the offer
endforeach;
?>
</div>
<?php  endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: But this code is index.php for example? i want an "If ". If the user have "offer", show icon with link to offer on index.php (post of user)

Comment: Im testing but the code have an error here: <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?> Maybe because the first <?php is not closed?

Comment: I'm trying to solve it but is difficult for my level! xD

Comment: One error solved, thanks! but have error in <?php
the_title(); // or anything you need

foreach ($offers as offer):
    echo offer['title']; // we display the title of the offer
endforeach;
?>

Comment: Sorry I missed the $ sign.

Comment: add $ before offer two times

Comment: thanks! i'm implementing in my code... only one question. when you said $offer is a singular of $offers, really?

Comment: don't work, only show the post title again, not the offer title :(

Comment: Ok Ok, works! show the title of offer, but in all posts, not only in the same author

Comment: or maybe is because the other user is administrator and he have all offers?

Comment: don't work, show the title of offer in all posts of index.php :( but works! :) on the way

Comment: don't help me more? :) or maybe drive me to the good way? I don't know why show in all post...

Comment: but thank you for all, even you don't help me more. really thanks